# How to achieve multiple icon hover transitions over one image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve two hover effects on an image.

First, when the user hovers over an image a plus icon on the top right corner of the image appears.

Second, when the user hovers over the plus the icon changes to: “Add to collection”.

All these events need to be smooth transitions.

My first problem is I can't get any smooth transitions going for the first hover.

My second problem is I have no idea how to achieve the second hover - I've done a lot of Google searches but this doesn't seem to be a common effect.

Here is the code I have tried so far (with fill murray placeholder image):

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
      <a href="#" class="item-link">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/582/580" alt="dimsum"> 
      </a>                  
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.item-link:hover:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;  
  position: absolute;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px; 
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/bWcylV3.png');
  border-radius: 50%;  
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

And here is the [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okusmp50/)

Here is the screenshots for what I want to achieve with the second hover:

[image: Add to collection screenshot]

Comment: It's not possible to `:hover` a pseudo-element like that so you may have to re-think here and use an actual element....perhaps a span?

Comment: Also, what kind of transition were you looking for.."smooth" doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D I am looking to do something similar to the "icon fade" transition used in hover.css: http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/ or the effect created with this bit of css: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/47815bf25752fe117da0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did a little bit changes in your mark up and and find a solution for your issue. Yes, It's not possible to `:hover` a `pseudo-element`. Added a new div btn-plus and a span text for convenience. This is done using pure `css`. Hope this helps :)

```css
.btn-plus:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;  
  position: absolute;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px; 
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/bWcylV3.png');
  border-radius: 50%;  
  top: 0px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.btn-plus{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 58px;
  top: 30px;
  right: 0;
  opacity : 0;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}
.item-link{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.item-link img{
  width: 100%;
}
span.text{
  position : absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
  z-index: 0;
  transition: all ease .5s;
   opacity : 0;
}
.item-link:hover .btn-plus{
   opacity : 1;
}
.btn-plus:hover span{
   opacity : 1;
  right: 30px
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
      <a href="#" class="item-link">
        <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/582/580" alt="dimsum">
        <div class="btn-plus">
            <span class="text">Add to list</span>
        </div> 
      </a>                  
    </div>
```

Comment: the only small thing is that when I run the snippet, there isn't a subtle fade-in transition when you hover, even though you use: `transition: all ease .25s;` do you know why this is the case?

Comment: @daneasterman check again. just edited the snippet. Previously I have used visibility  property to  hide and show the elements, now   Used opacity and now the transition works fine. Do u still face the problem?

Comment: Thanks again Junu, that works! I just adjusted it slightly to make the first hover a bit smoother by changing it to `ease-in` instead of `all ease` and increasing the interval to 0.75s instead of 0.5s. My edits are in this fiddle now: https://jsfiddle.net/q5Lzduuh/7/